# How to get some object we need from submenu in some array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Hi , hear i have some problem with my code bellow,
in this case i want to print my title object from object submenu, but i get some error like this
output :
undefined
2
3**

here is my code

```
const menu = [
        {
            title : "1",
            submenu :[
                {
                    title : 'gilbert lua',
                },
                {
                    title : 'pemai',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            title : "2",
        },
        {
            title : "3",
        }
    ];
    
const data = menu.map((e)=> {
    test(e.submenu,e.title)
});
function test(e,f){
    // const submenu = e.title;
     const testing = e? (e.title) : (f);
     console.log(testing);
}
```

thankyou

Comment: The `.map()` doesn't return anything. And you do nothing with `data`. Therefor `.map()` is the wrong tool

Comment: _"i get some error like this output : undefined 2 3"_ - `undefined` might be an unexpected result, but it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `const testing = e? (e.title) : (f);` if `e` is not null,then it's an array,we can use `forEach` to print this array

Note: it's a bad practice to iterate element using `map` instead of `forEach`

```js
const menu = [
        {
            title : "1",
            submenu :[
                {
                    title : 'gilbert lua',
                },
                {
                    title : 'pemai',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            title : "2",
        },
        {
            title : "3",
        }
    ];
    
const data = menu.map((e)=> {
    test(e.submenu,e.title)
});
function test(e,f){
     if(e){
       e.forEach(i => {
         console.log(i.title)
       })
     }else{
       // according to your question,this line might be not needed
       console.log(f)
     }
}
```

Comment: hi friend, thank you very much for the solution you have provided, now I have managed to solve the problem
you are so great

Comment: Thanks for doing the right thing on the dupe question